# Toggling TraceSwitch at runtime

Tags: c#, trace, system.net, traceswitch

I'm trying to get access to some diagnostic information available in the .NET System.Net tracing functionality in my application.

I am aware that I can set the tracing level using the appropriate .config, but I was hoping to be able to toggle the switch programatically.  (i.e. turn tracing on during particular parts of my program execution).

Is there a way for me to toggle the TraceSwitch/TraceSources used by the System.Net tracing functionality in code?

I'm aware of [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526247/is-it-possible-to-set-traceswitch-programmatically-mimicking-app-config-entry), but that situation seems different because the underlying issue there is that the library in question is creating a new TraceSwitch for each write call.

Comment: what is "System.Net tracing functionality"? Did you mean .Net's System namespace?

Comment: Still a valid question 8 years later. Hopefully there is a solution by now!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty you could try using reflection to toggle the private static bool System.Net.Logging.s_LoggingEnabled (.NET 2).

See further details and alternatives in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049442/system-net-httpwebrequest-tracing-without-using-files-or-app-config/4017432).